# can someone tell me what DKW 1938 car is it?

Tags: old-cars, identify-this, identification

i think it is F8, but it have round on doors, do you know, what is it? Thank for your time!

[image: front]

[image: interior]

[image: right]

[image: engine]
[image: back]
[image: label]
[![interior front][7]][7]

[7]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKg6L.jpg[image: this f7 from link have no round on doors]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Considering in your fourth image down (of the engine compartment), there's a large metal drum (of some sort) with an Audi symbol on it, plus in the sixth image down the placard appears to be in German, I'm highly doubting this is an Oldsmobile.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 definitely not an Olds.. it's a DKW of some description (strictly speaking that's not the "Audi" symbol in 1938 - it's the Auto Union A-G logo) I'm thinking it's either an F-5 or F-6

Comment: @motosubatsu - No worries. I think the Olds tag was added by mistake. I'll correct that ... and thanks for the heads up on the "Auto Union A-G" logo thing!

Answer (score 1):

As a 1938 car, it's too early to be an F8.

My best guess is that it's an F7 Meisterklasse Saloon (hence the 690 cubic centimeter rating on the plate).

I'm not sure what you mean by radiun on doors but bear in mind that as an 80 year old vehicle, the chances of components having been added or removed are far greater than a more recent car.

More info on the DKW F7 is available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DKW_F7)

Comment: Good spot on it being a Meisterklasse! The Reichsklasse was a 584cc.

Comment: radiun i mean rounded door :) do you think its "normal"?

Comment: They look like standard F7 doors to me.

Comment: I added photo for What i mean

Comment: The rounding around the B-pillar is what I think you mean - not "normal" for an F7 no but looking at the car I they look like the doors on a F7 Luxus Cabriolet so it's possible there was some variation in the doors or perhaps it's simply had work done at some point.

Comment: Many cars of the period would be finished by coachbuilders.  It's a bit of a lost art now but certain car makers didn't even sell finished cars, just rolling chassis for coachbuilders to add their own bodies to.  It's possible something like this was done when the car was new or it's possibly been added later.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [DKW F-7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DKW_F7) - it can't be an F-5 as they had stopped production by then, and it can't be the F-8 as they weren't made until 1939.

DKW was part of the Auto Union AG Group which at the time was a group consisting of four separate brands (Audi, Horch, DKW, Wanderer), so while the logo in the fourth picture appears to modern eyes as the Audi logo, it's not. The Auto Union logo was four rings to represent the interlocking of the four companies. Following WWII the displaced execs of the original Auto Union AG formed Auto Union GmbH which spent the next few decades transitioning into the Audi of today.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 They don't call me Master of Useless Trivia for nothing :)